# SQL Query works fine in PHPMyAdmin but not with mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

The following SQL query works perfectly fine when I run it with PHPMyAdmin but when I run it from a web page I get an error. I have looked around on StackOverflow for similar questions and have tried their suggestions but alas... Does anyone have an idea why it won't work on the web page?

The SQL query after variables have been put in (example):

```sql
SELECT place FROM locations WHERE (( 69.1 * ( latitude - 51.4700000 ) ) * ( 69.1 * (latitude - 51.4700000 ) )) + ( ( 69.1 * ( longitude - 5.5528000 ) * COS( 51.4700000 / 57.3 )) * ( 69.1 * ( longitude - 5.5528000 ) * COS( 51.4700000 / 57.3 ) ) ) < 976.5625 ORDER BY ((69.1 * ( latitude - 51.4700000 ) ) * ( 69.1 * ( latitude - 51.4700000 ) )) + ( ( 69.1 * ( longitude - 5.5528000 ) * COS( 51.4700000 / 57.3 ) ) * ( 69.1 * ( longitude - 5.5528000 ) * COS(51.4700000 / 57.3 ) ) ) ASC
```

The PHP ($radius and $start are defined a little before this):

```php
$latitude = $start['latitude'];
$longitude = $start['longitude'];
$r = pow($radius, 2);
$inrange = "SELECT place FROM locations_2 WHERE ((69.1 * (latitude - $latitude)) * (69.1 * (latitude - $latitude))) + ((69.1 * (longitude - $longitude) * COS($latitude / 57.3)) * (69.1 * (longitude - $longitude) * COS($latitude / 57.3))) < $r ORDER BY ((69.1 * (latitude - $latitude)) * (69.1 * (latitude - $latitude))) + ((69.1 * (longitude - $longitude) * COS($latitude / 57.3)) * (69.1 * (longitude - $longitude) * COS($latitude / 57.3))) ASC";
$result = mysql_query($inrange) or die(mysql_error());
```

The error message I get is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')) * (69.1 * (`latitude` - ))) + ((69.1 * (`longitude` - ) * COS( / 57.3)) * (69' at line 1
```

What's even stranger is that it worked... I wrote it all down, just the way I'm presenting it to you now, and was happy to see it worked just fine. That was earlier today. Now an hour or so ago I tried it again and for some reason it stopped working. I truly don't remember changing a thing.

EDIT

Thanks everyone. I figured it out and it turned out I made a stupid mistake. It worked earlier today because all the users had their location set. Now, I have a few users that don't so while looping through them the longitude and latitude came up empty.

Comment: Can you echo the values of $latitude and $longitude?

Comment: Also - get rid of the mess! Do something like:

`SELECT place, ((69.1 * ( latitude - 51.4700000 ) ) * ( 69.1 * ( latitude - 51.4700000 ) )) + ( ( 69.1 * ( longitude - 5.5528000 ) * COS( 51.4700000 / 57.3 ) ) * ( 69.1 * ( longitude - 5.5528000 ) * COS(51.4700000 / 57.3 ) ) ) AS distance FROM locations WHERE distance < 976.5625 ORDER BY distance ASC`

Much nicer no? Less repetition :-)

Comment: echo the full query with `echo $inrange` before mysql_query to be sure that 'that' also works in PHPMyAdmin

Comment: LuisSiquot I did, that's the first SQL query I show. It's the exact $inrange I use in the PHP.

David Hehe thanks for cleaning that up for me! I will make use of it once I get everything to work :)

RyanKempt 51.4700000 and 5.5528000 - works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your error message it seems like `$latitude` and `$longitude` does not contain any values. You probably want to check that `$start` is properly set. This is all I can help you with since I do not know what `$start` is and how you're getting it.

Comment: Thanks, I did an echo on $latitude and $longitude and they are fine, returning: 51.4700000 and 5.5528000

Comment: @Galadre ... I have a hard time believing that... If they were your error message would contain their values.

Comment: Why would I lie? Hm, in fact... I can show you the page and echo the values for you there if you would like and then let it continue till the error message.

Comment: Ah I figured it out. Thanks though and I'll accept your answer because what you said made me realize that I forgot to check if the user has his/her location set. I'm looping through users and what I show here is inside of a while loop... some users don't have a location, so they don't have a longitude or latitude either. Thanks again!

Comment: @Galadre ..Glad I could help even though you did the hard work! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if ((isset($start['latitude']))&&(isset($start['longitude']))){
$latitude = $start['latitude'];
$longitude = $start['longitude'];
$r = pow($radius, 2);
$inrange = "SELECT place FROM locations_2 WHERE ((69.1 * (latitude - $latitude)) * (69.1 *    (latitude - $latitude))) + ((69.1 * (longitude - $longitude) * COS($latitude / 57.3)) * (69.1 * (longitude - $longitude) * COS($latitude / 57.3))) < $r ORDER BY ((69.1 * (latitude - $latitude)) * (69.1 * (latitude - $latitude))) + ((69.1 * (longitude - $longitude) * COS($latitude / 57.3)) * (69.1 * (longitude - $longitude) * COS($latitude / 57.3))) ASC";
$result = mysql_query($inrange) or die(mysql_error());

}else
{
echo "error";
}
```

or

put $latitude,$latitude into {} in query

```
$inrange = "SELECT place FROM locations_2 WHERE ((69.1 * (latitude - {$latitude})) * (69.1 *    (latitude - {$latitude}))) + ((69.1 * (longitude - {$longitude}) * COS({$latitude} / 57.3)) * (69.1 * (longitude - {$longitude}) * COS({$latitude} / 57.3))) < $r ORDER BY ((69.1 * (latitude - {$latitude})) * (69.1 * (latitude - {$latitude}))) + ((69.1 * (longitude - {$longitude}) * COS({$latitude} / 57.3)) * (69.1 * (longitude - {$longitude}) * COS($latitude / 57.3))) ASC";
```

Comment: latitude and longitude are set and fine. See my other comment to Erik's post.

Comment: I just tried enclosing them in brackets but still the same error.